# 2D Vector Sorting Algorithm

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to write a sorting loop that sorts a 2D vector based on the values under a column that represents time. It should sort the entries in ascending order (Sample data below). If the value under the time column is null/ "-" It should be pushed to the bottom.

This is what I have so far;

```
bool hasSwapped;

do {
    hasSwapped = false;
    for (int nor = 0; nor < (rows - 1); nor++)
    {
        //nor stands for no of rows
        int t = 5;
        if (Champ[nor][t] < Champ[nor + 1][t]&& Champ[nor][t] != "-")
            continue;
        else
        {
            swap(Champ[nor], Champ[nor + 1]);
            hasSwapped = true;
        }
    }
} while (hasSwapped);
```

However, when I run the program, it gets stuck on the loop somehow. The program runs and sorts everything without any time values as '-' but once you add '-' values to the table then the program doesn't output anything. I believe the problem comes in when I try to account for the "-" values in my if statement. Can someone suggest a solution to my problem?

Sample unsorted data
(I used '/' as separators of the various entries and the time value in question is the second last value in every row)

```
1  / BrianOkoth /24-02-1999/    3/  100M/   -/  DNF

2   /HanselRack/    13-09-1988/ 2/  200M/   1.54/   Q

3   /FalloTimmy/    12-09-1973/ 1/  100M/   0.32/   -

4   /RodneyJohn/    14-08-1984/ 2/  500M/   3.92/   DQ

5   /GarryField/    02-02-2001/ 3/  100M/   0.90/   Q

6   /WallowGon/ 03-03-1977/ /1  /500M   /3.4/   Q

7   /TerryFlops/    24-04-1975/ 1/  200M/   1.3/    Q

8   /DinghyRoes/    13-06-1989/ 3/  500M/   -/  DNF

9   /WorryNot/  23-07-1956/ 2/  200M/   3.2 /Q

10  /GogoPopo/  24-04-1977/ 1/  100M/   3.0/    -
```

mcve:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
#include <Cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int rows;
    cout << "Enter number rows -> ";
    cin >> rows;
    vector < vector<string>>Champ;
    //input  your own data into the 2d vector Champ that is similar to the 
sample data given in the question.
    //sorting loop
    bool hasSwapped;
    do {
        hasSwapped = false;
        for (int nor = 0; nor < (rows - 1); nor++)
        {
            //nor stands for no of rows
            int t = 5;
            if (Champ[nor][t] < Champ[nor + 1][t] && Champ[nor][t] != "-")
                continue;
            else
            {
                swap(Champ[nor], Champ[nor + 1]);
                hasSwapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (hasSwapped);
    //output loop
    cout << "NO     Name    DOB     Heat    D(m)    Time(s) Status" << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Champ.size(); i++)
    {
        int in = 0;
        for (int n = 1; n < rows + 1; n++)
        {
            std::string s = std::to_string(n);
            Champ[in][0] = s;
            in++;
        }
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Champ[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << Champ[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What's `Champ`?  I suspect that `!=` isn't doing what you think it is

Comment: Is there some spectacularly good reason you've decided to write a bubble sort instead of using the `std::sort` that's built into the standard library?

Comment: Representing the records by objects (of class type) instead of columns of a 2D-vector would make the code much easier.

Comment: @StephanLechner Possibly a homework question, so there may be external requirements that we are not aware of.

Comment: @JerryCoffin bubble sort is a very fast sort when it's nearly sorted already .... and related to other comments; it's a common learning algorithm.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? What happens if you run it with a single row? What happens if you run it with two or three rows? Does it work if none of the rows have `'-'` as the time? Have you verified the contents of `Champ` are what you expect?

Comment: @UKMonkey: bubble sort is mediocre when data is already almost sorted (e.g., insertion sort is consistently better). "Because I have to for homework." would be a reasonable answer to the question I asked (which is why I asked a question rather than just saying: "use std::sort").

Comment: @Useless well, the program runs and sorts everything without any time values as '-' but once you add '-' values to the table then the program doesn't output anything. Also, i have verified that the contents of Champ are what i expected, yes.

Comment: This is all relevant information that should be in the question. As is the rest of your [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and I do mean _minimal_ - no-one wants to see code for loading these Champs in from a file)

Comment: @JerryCoffin I didn't even know that std::sort was a thing! How do i use it to sort this 2d vector?

Comment: @Brokoth: See my answer--but the short version is: use structs, not 2D arrays, and define comparison for those structs based on the correct field.

Comment: @UKMonkey Champ is the 2D vector containing the sample data shown in the question. And, I thought that != means not equals to?

Comment: @Useless ok, i made the necessary changes.

Comment: @Brokoth there's a != for std::string; and != char*  if champ were char* then != would compare pointer values; and not contents; your code however shows that it's a string... which means you're not hitting the traditional pitfall.  This is why it's always asked for a minimal, complete, verifiable example!

Comment: @UKMonkey Ok, know that you know it is a string. Do you know how to solve this problem? Also, i added a mcve.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, a 2D vector is the wrong place to start with this. I'd start with a `struct` with a member for each field in the file, and define comparison for those structures. Since the time field you want is a floating point number anyway, and those (on nearly all reasonable implementations) support a representation of `infinity`, I'd use that to get the behavior you want.

```
if (foo == '-')
    record.time = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
else
    record.time = std::stod(foo);
```

As you'd expect, `infinity` sorts as being larger than any other number, so you don't have to do anything special with the comparison to get these to sort into the order you want--all the ones that had numbers present sorted by that number, followed by all the ones with a '-' for the time field.

Simplifying a bit (leaving out most of the unrelated fields), code might look something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>

struct item { 
    std::string name;
    double time;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, item &i) { 
        std::string line;
        std::getline(input, line);

        std::istringstream is(line);

        std::getline(is, i.name, '/');

        char ch;
        is >> ch;
        if (ch == '-') {
            is.ignore(1);
            i.time = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
        }
        else {
            is.unget();
            is >> i.time;
        }
        return input;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, item const &i) { 
        return os << i.name << '\t' << i.time;
    }

    bool operator<(item const &other) { 
        return time < other.time;
    }
};

int main() { 
    std::istringstream input {
    R"(BrianOkoth/ -/
HanselRack/  1.54/
FalloTimmy/ 0.32/
RodneyJohn/ 3.92/
GarryField/ 0.90/
WallowGon/  3.4/
TerryFlops/ 1.3/
DinghyRoes/ -/
WorryNot/   3.2 /
GogoPopo/   3.0/)"};

    std::vector<item> items { std::istream_iterator<item>(input), {}};

    std::copy(items.begin(), items.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<item>(std::cout, "\n"));

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::sort(items.begin(), items.end());
    std::copy(items.begin(), items.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<item>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
BrianOkoth  inf
HanselRack  1.54
FalloTimmy  0.32
RodneyJohn  3.92
GarryField  0.9
WallowGon   3.4
TerryFlops  1.3
DinghyRoes  inf
WorryNot    3.2
GogoPopo    3

FalloTimmy  0.32
GarryField  0.9
TerryFlops  1.3
HanselRack  1.54
GogoPopo    3
WorryNot    3.2
WallowGon   3.4
RodneyJohn  3.92
BrianOkoth  inf
DinghyRoes  inf
```

Comment: I see. We hadn't yet touched on this data structure in class but I'm definitely going to use it. Thanks for giving your time.